# Head to head - what to do if both teams lost

Tags: football, statistics

Normally a football match can end with these results:

- Victory for home team
- Victory for away team
- Draw

But...

If a judge issues a resolution, he can decide to assign that both teams lost the match.

This is a case of public order problems (violence between supporters and so on).

An example: Taranto - Cavese, italian serie C2 girone C season 2004/2005. Both teams lost the match after the judge's decision.

How do I consider this match in head to head statistics between these two teams?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: when you have an head to head table you have (for example): Team A W 4 D 1 L 1 and Team B W 1 D 1 L 4 but in these cases? the lost games are not specular to winning games of other team. Right?

Comment: Did you check exactly the words of the decision? It surprises me that they would decide a result of both teams losing. It would seem easier to either say that the result was null and void, and the match would not be replayed, or to award a result but assign a points deduction for one or both teams. See for example the original decision (later overturned) in Serbia vs Albania of awarding Serbia a 3-0 win and docking them 3pts. http://www.caughtoffside.com/2014/10/24/uefa-face-backlash-following-controversial-decision-to-award-serbia-3-0-walkover-win-against-albania/

Comment: You ignore it I suppose

Comment: @Fillet: Either teams are losing because their supporters have caused incidents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I didn't think this could ever happen, and that any punishment would be achieved by docking points, but at least according to the [table in Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_C2_2004-2005) some games resulted in **both** teams losing.

Summing the columns for wins and losses, you can see that 222 games were won, and 226 games lost. The total goal difference is also at -12.

[image]

For a head-to-head record I suggest using @Don_Biglia's suggestion and just listing the wins for each team, and the draws, for example as found here: http://www.statto.com/football/teams/head-to-head/manchester-city/manchester-united

[image: Head to head chart Manchester City v United]

If there is a match where both teams lost, then the match will not feature at all in the table.

The only drawback is that this could mislead somebody as the total number of matches played between the teams. Possibly a footnote could be added "data excludes game from DD.MM.2005 where both teams lost due to crowd violence"

The only other option I can think of would be to have four rows/columns: Team A Win / Team B Win  / Draw / Other. But it would probably add much complexity just to cover one or two unusual cases.